# Git - How to change credential [remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied fatal: Authentication failed for]

Tags: git, gitlab

When installing my Git repository (GitKraken with GitLab), I entered the wrong password.
So Git returns this error:

```
"remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for'https://gitlab.com/mygitproject/'"
```

It's not offering the option to retype my password. So I'm stuck....

Comment: Does this solve your problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246876/linux-how-to-remove-git-credentials

Comment: Consider using ssh instead.

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10.
Grammy: This solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: I also uninstalled / Reinstalled Git, without success.

Comment: No idea what their setup is, but if you're on Windows try looking under 'Windows credentials' (type it in on the start menu), and delete anything that looks git related

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitLab remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied and fatal Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860772/gitlab-remote-http-basic-access-denied-and-fatal-authentication)

Answer (score 12):

I recently had the same problem on Windows. My credentials was recently been updated in Active Directory. Git bash stores credentials in the Windows Vault using Generic Credentials in the 'Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager'. After updating my password to match the current value I was able to 'git push'.

Answer (score 4):

I would always advise to use SSH, but if you insist on using this approach you should be able to go (in GitKraken) to

> Preferences->Authentication

and in General tab select the option to

> 'Forget all Username/Passwords'

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case my password was expired and it was not allowing me to enter my new password-

Below is the command I need to run to fix this issue:-

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

After running above command it asks me again my updated ***username*** and ***password***.

Here is the [source for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860772/gitlab-remote-http-basic-access-denied-and-fatal-authentication/51036707#51036707).